# Profile picture was not updated automatically

Tags: cakephp-3.0

When i update the image from website, it was not updated automatically. When i logged-out and again login into website then it was updated. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Browser cache? Session not being updated?

Comment: hi @GregSchmidt i clear the browser cache but session not update.That's why value (image) is not updated